# append several rows to csv

Tags: python, csv

I've hopefully got a pretty easy one for you all! I need to append several rows to a csv. Here's the general structure:

```
f=((np.array(i)).tolist())
g=((np.array(j)).tolist())
h=((np.array(k)).tolist())

with open('output.csv','a') as z:
    z.write(",".join(map(str,f)))
```

This is great for a single row of data! However, I have several rows to add. If I try doing this, all of the data is appended as one row!

```
f=((np.array(i)).tolist())
g=((np.array(j)).tolist())
h=((np.array(k)).tolist())

with open('output.csv','a') as f:
    z.write(",".join(map(str,f)))
    z.write(",".join(map(str,g)))
    z.write(",".join(map(str,h)))
```

My question boils down to: how do I append several lists to my csv as separate rows? Can I slap a `\n` somewhere?

Comment: You can, and you should - right at the end of each row.

Comment: I am still not clear where I should be putting the `\n`. I just keep getting "unexpected character after line continuation character"

Comment: Out of curiousity, what are `i, j,` and `k`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, they are numpy arrays that I am doing arithmetic with

Comment: Then what's the point of `(np.array(i)).tolist()`, why not just `tolist()`?

Comment: What I have now works. I'm not trying to break it. I'm going to be using it for large files with thousands of entries. It's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to roll your own CSV writer. You should use the `csv` module's CSVWriter object:

```
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w') as store:
    writer = csv.writer(store)
    for row in [i, j, k]:
        writer.writerow((np.array(row)).tolist())
```

Comment: I receive "can't assign to function call".

Comment: @JohnM: please use edited code. Btw, +1 to OP of this answer for recommending using standard library.

Comment: that did the job. Could you construct a more general form of this as another comment not only for myself but for others who might come across the question in the future? i.e, with generic lists rather than numpy arrays

Comment: @JohnM this *does work* with generic lists... why are you using `numpy`?

Comment: `general form of this as another comment not only for myself but for others who might come across the question in the future?` the function `writerow` takes a list as its parameter. `np.array` is creating an numpy array which is then immediately cast to a list.